# Google Auth Popup not working for React 17 App; Getting React warning is this why or how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, function

As shown in description, I am working on a React project and utilizing Firebase for Auth and popup is not firing but I think it might have to do with this warning from React. The warning I am getting from React is that Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
I have been researching this and trying to problem solve for 2 days. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you!!

Here is my Firebase Utils code for the auth:

```js
const config = {
  My config info
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);



const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
.then(function (result) {
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})



export default firebase;
```

Now my Custom Button Component in React 17

```js
import React from 'react';
import './custom-button.styles.scss';

const CustomButton = ({children, isGoogleSignIn, ...otherProps}) => (
    <button
      className={`${isGoogleSignIn ? 'google-sign-in' : ''} custom-button`}
      {...otherProps}>
        {children}
    </button>
);

export default CustomButton;
```

Lastly my signin component in React

```js
lass SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ email: '', password: '' })
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;

        this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className='sign-in'>
            <h2>I already have an account</h2>
            <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            name='email'
            type='email'
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.email}
            label='email'
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            name='password'
            type='password'
            value={this.state.password}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            label='password'
            required
          />
          <div className='buttons'>
            <CustomButton type='submit'> Sign in </CustomButton>
            <CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle} isGoogleSignIn>
                Sign in with Google
            </CustomButton>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. The firebase config file should have had a .then and .catch for the promise. Once I added this, it works fine now. I researched 3 days to figure this out. Taking a course, and the guy who produced this course didn't add this, although it was two years ago maybe it wasn't required then, but it is now.